# Fill in the blanks with the number in words

Tags: wordplay

Here is an easy one

This sentence has ______ letters.

Fill in the blanks in with a number in words.

Comment: Please look at the tag wikis before posting puzzles. This is not a logic puzzle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two solutions with the implied constraint of the words being numbers:

> "thirty-one" and "thirty-three".

However, there are several more possibilities:

- "more than two" (as @Zandar said)
- "several"
- "not exactly fifty"
- ""
- "spaces and"
- "an underscore in place of"
- "a period after forty-two"
- "144 characters, 11 of which are digits, 26 of which are spaces, 4 of which are punctuation, and finally 105 of which are"

(Check that last one out, it works.)

Comment: As stated, "more than two" would also work.

Comment: Man, too quick...I wasted 5 minutes in writing the question, u answered it in less than 2 minutes..

Comment: No, I expected a number in its words. Look at the title.

Comment: @Sid: Titles generally shouldn't have information important to the puzzle. They should describe the puzzle briefly. For instance, I'd title this something like "Self-referential letter count".

Comment: This question will then be too broad. I expected a number in the words. Answers like several, more than two will be too vague and not an accurate answer. As for the characters, good find that, never expected that although I was just looking for letters.

Comment: "22" is also a solution

Comment: @Eridan No, as the OP has stated before [here](/a/36292/12114#comment107450_36292), they want the number *in words*.